# How do I know which app services are using an Application Insights resource

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal, azure-monitoring

I have an [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-app-map) resource on my Azure subscription which was added by previous developers, and I am trying to understand which app services are configured with this Application Insights resource.

Because we have 20 app services and all are configured to only 3 application insight resources.

So I want to know which applications are configured to which App Insights which are tracking the insights of the applications like server requests, server response time, page load time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We can check that by going through application map of that application insight resource.
Application Map gives the topology of the related components.

So if you are having multiple app services configured to this one application insight then you will be able to see multiple topological map of app services with their related components in application map.

and from this you will be able to see which all app services are configured for this app insight resource.

To check this open the application insight resource and under this blade you will find application map. 
Once you click on Application Map you will see all the resources configured to this app insight resource.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-app-map